# Can't get expo push notification token from some regions

Tags: react-native, expo

I know expo.io is restricted to some regions, or so I have seen. But the documents and everything else is accessible (I have tried this only for Cuba). Why can't I get the Cuba push notification token? also restricted? When I try to call the  `getExpoPushTokenAsync` method, i get an error:

```
Couldn't get push token for device. Check that your FCM configuration is valid
```

I have tried it on networks in other countries and it works. Is there anything I can do to make my push notifications work in Cuba?

Answer (score 1):

I work on Expo.

I think its likely there is a bug in the code on the client that is calling `getExpoPushTokenAsync` here because there are no restrictions I'm aware of that would cause this not to work in Cuba.

Comment: When i try to access https://expo.io from Cuba i get a timeout response, every time, i'ts not a problem of internet speed, maybe it's the internet provider, i dont know if that is possible. And https://docs.expo.io responds correctly. Maybe the url to get  the push token is getting timeout for the same reason that https://expo.io is getting timeout

Comment: Even the OTA Updates are't aviable from cuba, the users have to run a VPN from another country to be able to get access to OTA Updates and be able to get the push notification token

Comment: From a quick search it doesn’t seem like s3 or cloudfront are blocked in cuba


maybe you are using an older version of the Expo Client on android that had these issues. Could you make sure the version is up to date by installing with `expo client:install:android` and then running the snack from the docs, just to rule out any problems with your code?

not being able to access expo.io at all is troubling, but there was a brief server outage yesterday and you may have tried during that.

Comment: I've been trying to access expo.io this days and i get the same timeout response, until yesterday i was using the last version of expo client and expo-cli, but i don't think Expo Client have participation on this, becouse the token is also unavailable in the compiled apk, i've read that in last realease Expo made changes in the `expo-notifications` library. So i have to download and test, but i'm not sure if that will fix the problem, becouse i'm saying i have not access to `expo.io` and i think that that is the couse of the problem

Comment: I cant run any snack because i can't access https://snack.expo.io either